# When using a scanner on a series of integers, how do I skip some integers?

Tags: java

The  following code for example

```
while (lineScan.hasNextLine()) {
   int x = lineScan.nextInt();
   x = lineScan.nextInt();
   x = lineScan.nextInt();
   x = lineScan.nextInt();
   x = lineScan.nextInt();
   System.out.println(x + "\n");
}
```

will print out every fifth integer.

Is there an easy way to skip over every fifth integer?

Comment: Skip over every fifth integer or print every fifth integer?

Answer (score 3):

```
while (lineScan.hasNextLine()) {
    for(int i=0; i<5; i++)
        x = lineScan.nextInt();

    System.out.println(x + "\n");
}
```

OR

```
while (lineScan.hasNextLine()) {
    for(int i=0; i<4; i++) 
        lineScan.nextInt();

    x = lineScan.nextInt();
    System.out.println(x + "\n");
}
```

Seems rather primitive, but, it works.

Answer (score 3):

I see lot's of folks checking the hasNextLine and then reading ints.  I've always been taught that if you check hasNextX you should follow this with a call to nextX, if the check passes, but never nextY.  In other words, if you check hasNextLine(), you should read in nextLine(), and if you want int, you should check hasNextInt() before reading in nextInt() with *one check for every read*.  In your situation, I'd read in the line and then manipulate it either with another Scanner object that works on just that line (don't forget to close it when done to save on resources!) or use String split.

For example if doing it the first way, I'd do something like:

```
  while (lineScan.hasNextLine()) {
     String line = lineScan.nextLine();

     Scanner innerScanner = new Scanner(line);
     int x = 0;
     while (innerScanner.hasNextInt()) {
        x = innerScanner.nextInt();
     }
     System.out.println("" + x);
     innerScanner.close();
  }
```

and for the second way:

```
  while (lineScan.hasNextLine()) {
     String line = lineScan.nextLine();

     String[] splitLine = line.split(" "); // the delimiter may be different! a comma?
     if (splitLine.length >= 5) {
        System.out.println(splitLine[4]);
     }
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

This will do:

```
int i = 0;
while(lineScan.hasNextLine()) {
   i++;
   int x = lineScan.nextInt();
   if (x%5 == 0) System.out.println(x + "\n");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just do `nextInt()` and ignore the result?

Answer (score 0):

Use a loop, I suppose:

```
while(lineScan.hasNextLine()) {
     for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++) lineScan.nextInt();
     System.out.println(Integer.toString(lineScan.nextInt()) + "\n"); // is this supposed to be "popularity"?
}
```

Comment: Probably because your code doesn't compile at all? Primitives doesn't have methods.

Comment: The `toString` is unnecessary as `+` would already implicitly do that. See also the other answers.

Comment: @BalusC: I like to be explicit. It helps keep things consistent between all languages.